# Refresh GUI graphs and take account of GUI modifications during the refresh (text, edit, popup uicontrol)

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I come here today because I am developping a GUI on Matlab 2007b (with GUIDE) in which I control some electronic equipments (oscilloscope, function generator => frequency, timebase, trigger, a lot of thing) and in this one I get the curves display on the oscilloscope screen to display them on my GUI on an axe. The oscilloscope refresh the signals according to the trigger, and I know I can't do the same thing on my GUI (the time to get the signal from the oscilloscope is pretty long compare to the trigger period).

What I wish is the next thing: I open my GUI, launch a infinite while loop in which I call the function which refresh my curves on my axes (so get the signals from the oscilloscope, and update the axe) and refresh each time is possible. BUT, what I wish also is that the user can always interact with my GUI : change the frequency of the signal on a generator, change the timebase of the oscilloscope, etc. Unfortunately (but logically), when I launch my while loop, I can't do anything more with my GUI.

Is it possible to do it? Interact with my GUI and call the callbacks functions associated to object the user is interacted with, wherease there is a "background" function which is executed? For information, I refresh my graphs getting the data from an oscilloscopa via the ethernet link.

Maybe it is about the BusyAction and Interruptible value of the object? Or maybe it is only possible with a timer? I never do such thing before so I looked for information on internet but it seems to be a little complicated.

Just a little advice could be the difference to unlock me. I thank you in advance for your help.

If I didn't give enough information, don't hesitate to tell me.

PS: here there is an image of my GUI and the axe above in which there is 2 curves I want to refresh each time is possible.

[First tab of my GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDbK0.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reliable way to accomplish this is to use a timer to periodically poll the oscilloscope and update your plots. Then, when the timer is not executing, anyone can interact with any of the controls in your GUI.

```
t = timer('TimerFcn', @checkOscilloscope, 'ExecutionMode', 'FixedRate', 'Period', 0.1);
start(t);

function checkOscilloscope(tmr, evnt)
    % Do your check of the oscilloscope here

    % Update plots

    % Force a redraw
    drawnow
end
```

Comment: First thank for your answer.

The problem is I have to set my timer period to 1ms (the minimum) and my function to update last 1 seconds some times so MATLAB don't manage correctly the action during the execution of my function and even with a drawnow my all actions on the GUI are not taking account. Because I try your solution which works when I have a "free" time between two executions of the timer (if the period of the timer is higher than the executin time of my function) but I am not in that case half time.

Comment: So do you think I am stuck in my case and the timer? Or is it because I don't manage correctly some properties of the timer or my GUI objects (BusyAction, Interruptible, ExecutionMode, etc) ? For information, I initialize my timer like this :

timer('TimerFcn', {@toto, handles}, 'BusyMode', 'Queue', 'ExecutionMode', 'FixedSpacing', 'Period', 0.001);

Comment: I did the test again. If I set my timer period to 0.001 ms and add a pause(3) in my function, the function is correctly called every 3 seconds but each action on my GUI is also correctly put in the queue list but the callback associated are only call when I finish the timer (ctrl+C) so I imagine MATLAB put in the queue list my update each millisecond instead of drop them, no? And it is why the callback of the GUI object are far in the queue list.

Comment: @MathieuGauquelin Nothing else can happen while your function is running so having a period of 1ms is meaningless if your function takes 3 seconds to run.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your answer. I change my way to see the problem and now my function is update every quarter of seconds and my function last a fifth of second so it is okay now. Thank you very much!